# How do I have a Javascript Array of a custom object which dynamically grows?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I am creating a Room Booking form using HTML5. The user enters information such as Date, Their name, room they are booking etc... Id like to then insert this information into an array of my own object that i've created. So, every time the user presses a button, it takes all the form data and inserts it into the array.

The array would be limited to something like 15 or 20...

I have managed to create a singular object below, but I am struggling to create an array of this object... and then i'd need to work out how to identify which index's in the array are empty..

```
function listItem(cal, lesson, date, notes, teacher, group){
  this.calChoice = cal;
  this.lessonChoice = lesson;
  this.date = date;
  this.notes = notes;
  this.teacher = teacher;
  this.group = group;
}

// ....

var list = new listItem(calchoice, lessonchoice, date, notes, teacher, group);
```

I'm sure its something ridiculously simple :S

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

quick shot:

```
var list = [];
list[list.length] = new listItem();
```

As `list.length` is the element count in the array. The index starts at `0` so list.length is the next "free" index.

Comment: Also `list.push(new listItem())` could be used.

Answer (score 1):

.push would be the appropriate way imo

```
list.push(new listItem(calchoice, lessonchoice, date, notes, teacher, group));
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare a list.

```
var mainList =[];
```

and whenever you create an object,

```
var list = new listItem(calchoice, lessonchoice, date, notes, teacher, group);
```

push it to the main list.

```
mainList.push(list);
```

Hope helps!

you could access each object through a for loop if you want.